# What is the alternative of [NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:withExtension: in iOS 3 SDK

Tags: ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios3.0

I am developing an iOS app using iOS 4.2 SDK, but I want the app to run on older devices like my iPhone 2G with iOS 3.1.3. I don't know what is the alternative for this code:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CoreDataApp" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

It crashes on my device, because the URLForResource:withExtension: method is iOS 4+.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its -

```
NSURL *aFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:path ofType:@"aif"]];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain path to your resource using `pathForResource:ofType:` method and then convert that path to URL using for example `+fileURLWithPath:` method in `NSURL` - both apis are available starting SDK 2.0.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreDataApp" ofType:@"momd"];
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```